# tkinter divide program into 3 parts?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create this:
[image]

I want to create those 3 parts, in every of them will be different content generated by computer and in the middle there will be huge text field.

**Solution from answers**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('500x500')

        #Textbox
        first_textbox = Text(self.root, width=25, height=10, bg='yellow')
        second_textbox = Text(self.root, width=25, height=10, bg='blue')
        third_textbox = Text(self.root, width=50, height=20, bg='red')


        # Packing
        first_textbox.grid(column=1, row=1)  
        second_textbox.grid(column=1, row=2)
        third_textbox.grid(column=2, row=1, rowspan=2)

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

appstart = GUI()
appstart.start()
```

Comment: The methods of layout out a GUI are fairly well documented. Have you read the documentation and tried to solve this problem before asking the question? See See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I know there is some grid and pack, and pack is using lines and rows

Comment: "I want this:" Is not the generally accepted method of asking a question.

Comment: Google revealed that tkinter has frames for this purpose. Although you could also achieve this with a grid layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.geometry('500x500')

        #Textbox
        first_textbox = Text(self.root, width=25, height=10, bg='yellow')
        second_textbox = Text(self.root, width=25, height=10, bg='blue')
        third_textbox = Text(self.root, width=50, height=20, bg='red')


        # Packing
        first_textbox.grid(column=1, row=1)  
        second_textbox.grid(column=1, row=2)
        third_textbox.grid(column=2, row=1, rowspan=2)

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

appstart = GUI()
appstart.start()
```

I would use effbot.org as a good resource. This code will give you a working example of how the grid system places widgets on a canvas. I made each of them a different color to help visualize this.